# seaborn scatterplot datetime xaxis too wide

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Depth': {0: 0.2,
  1: 0.4,
  2: 0.4,
  3: 0.4,
  4: 0.4,
  5: 0.4,
  6: 0.6000000000000001,
  7: 0.4,
  8: 3.2,
  9: 2.0},
 'DateTimeUTC': {0: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:25:08'),
  1: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:25:49'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:27:06'),
  3: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:32:11'),
  4: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:32:59'),
  5: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:34:02'),
  6: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:35:38'),
  7: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:37:04'),
  8: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:39:08'),
  9: Timestamp('2018-03-28 06:40:52')}})
```

which looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr><th></th><th>Depth</th><th>DateTimeUTC</th></tr>
  <tr><th>0</th><td>0.2</td><td>2018-03-28 06:25:08</td></tr>
  <tr><th>1</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:25:49</td></tr>
  <tr><th>2</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:27:06</td></tr>
  <tr><th>3</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:32:11</td></tr>
  <tr><th>4</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:32:59</td></tr>
  <tr><th>5</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:34:02</td></tr>
  <tr><th>6</th><td>0.6</td><td>2018-03-28 06:35:38</td></tr>
  <tr><th>7</th><td>0.4</td><td>2018-03-28 06:37:04</td></tr>
  <tr><th>8</th><td>3.2</td><td>2018-03-28 06:39:08</td></tr>
  <tr><th>9</th><td>2.0</td><td>2018-03-28 06:40:52</td></tr>
</table>
```

Note the all `DateTimeUTC` are within 2018. When I try to plot depth vs time using sns.scatterplot I get:

```
sns.scatterplot('DateTimeUTC', 'Depth', data=df)
```

[image: plot]

Why does the X-axis start at year 2000? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the question as an issue on Github, and got this [great response](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1641#issuecomment-452078518). Basically, the problem is that `plt.scatter` does not deal with dates well, and seaborn uses it. If seaborn will add a type check for the x-axis, which uses `plt.plot_date` for date values instead, this will be fixed. In the meanwhile, one can create a custom version of `sns.scatterplot` that does excatly that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use seaborns [lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot) which does have a correct x-axis:

```
sns.lineplot(x='DateTimeUTC', y='Depth', data=df, marker='o')
```

Or you could use:

```
plt.plot(df['DateTimeUTC'], df['Depth'], linestyle='None', marker='o')
```