# seaborn axis range not fitting data range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to create a simple scatterplot(I have created several in the past) as i  want to understand the relationship ratio between service desk created tickets and service desk closed tickets. This 2 features are timestamps but when i plot the graph the X and Y axis seem to be of a much larger range than needed as the data that i have goes from 2017 to 2019 and the graph plots from 2000 to 2020. i have tried amending the `plt.xlim()` to `plt.xlim(2016,2020)` but that produces a plot where the axis in question has values that don't make sense (see picture attached)
my code is the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=data['Created'], y=data['Closed'])
```

and this produces the following graph:

[image]

when i try to amend the `plt.xlim()` i get the following graph:
[image]

and here is some of the data that i am trying to graph:

```
          Created                  Closed
13  2018-01-16 16:23:21     2018-01-21 16:23:55
14  2018-01-11 17:51:18     2018-01-16 17:55:15
15  2018-01-12 13:03:50     2018-01-22 14:01:12
16  2018-01-11 13:28:55     2018-01-21 15:11:04
17  2018-01-04 09:58:36     2018-01-09 10:01:34
18  2018-01-23 09:19:36     2018-02-22 15:00:06
20  2019-04-09 10:50:54     2019-04-14 10:56:27
21  2019-04-08 19:22:49     2019-04-14 14:25:26
22  2019-04-09 12:34:24     2019-04-15 14:37:47
23  2019-04-09 17:22:10     2019-04-17 17:00:20
24  2019-04-09 09:58:52     2019-04-17 11:30:13
25  2019-04-08 20:08:01     2019-04-09 22:01:30
26  2019-04-09 18:40:13     2019-04-10 22:26:45
27  2019-04-09 19:29:04     2019-04-15 10:00:48
28  2019-04-10 02:43:15     2019-04-15 02:46:54
29  2019-04-10 03:04:36     2019-04-15 03:07:27
30  2019-04-10 03:12:02     2019-04-15 03:14:33
```

To reproduce the problem I am facing, run the following before plotting:

```
data['Created']=pd.to_datetime(data['Created'])
data['Closed']=pd.to_datetime(data['Closed'])
```

I am aware that there is an issue with seaborn and plotting date time but there has to be a way to plot the data properly.
So my question is, how can i get the plot to zoom into the range of where the data has been created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [seaborn scatterplot datetime xaxis too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050472/seaborn-scatterplot-datetime-xaxis-too-wide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do

```
plt.xlim(2016, 2020)
```

`plt` set the limits to the **integer** values of 2016 and 2020, which converted to timestamp will be about 2000 nanoseconds from epoch time, i.g.

```
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020')
```

That's why you don't get to see your scatters anymore. Instead, pass to `plt.xlim` the corresponding timestamps:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=data['Created'], y=data['Closed'])

plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01'), # pd.to_datetime('2016') also works
        pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'))
plt.show()
```

and you can get:

[image]

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! I knew there was a way to use seaborn and dates. Thanks for going the extra mile and making it work under my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a known issue in `sns.scatterplot`.
You can solve your problem in different ways, here are two:

Use a simple matplotlib plot and set the linestyle and marker:

```
sns.set()
fig,ax= plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(df['Created'], df['Closed'],linestyle='None', marker='o')
```

Or use `ax.plot_date`

```
sns.set()
fig,ax= plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,5))
ax.plot_date(df['Created'], df['Closed'])
```

[image]